# Php Hidden field form doesn't submit to MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have a hidden field on my form that I'll submit to MySql database via php.

**Form**

```
 <form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
 <dl>
 <dt><label class="formComment" for="body">Message *</label></dt>
 <dd><textarea class="inputbox" name="body" id="body"></textarea></dd>
 <dt><label class="formName" for="name">Name *</label></dt>
 <dd><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="name" id="name" /></dd>
 <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="tree"/> 
 </dl>
 <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

**submit.php**

```
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO comments(post_id,name,url,email,body)
                VALUES (
                    '".$arr['post_id']."',
                    '".$arr['name']."',
                    '".$arr['body']."'
                )");

$arr['dt'] = date('r',time());
$arr['id'] = mysql_insert_id();
```

When I submit this to MySql, only the values from name and body (message) appears in my MysQl database, but the hidden value doesn't pass through.

what's my mistake here?

Also I want to have the hidden value as the title of the page, which is under h2 tag. I tried something like this (which is bad, I know).

```
 <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo <h2></h2> ?>"/>
```

Comment: pls echo some php/mysql errors

Comment: what is the output of print_r($_POST); ??

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo "<h2></h2>" ?>"/>
```

You had no quotes after echo

Why is `action=""` empty?

```
 <form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
 <dl>
 <dt><label class="formComment" for="body">Message *</label></dt>
 <dd><textarea class="inputbox" name="body" id="body"></textarea></dd>
 <dt><label class="formName" for="name">Name *</label></dt>
 <dd><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="name" id="name" /></dd>
 <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="tree"/> 
 </dl>
 <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>  
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo "<h2></h2>" ?>"/>
```

Comment: `action` can be empty if you want the form to submit to the same page.